# Hibernate Named Query excluding null values

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using the following named query to get results from the database based on parameters I am passing from a JSP page.

```
<query name="getData"><![CDATA[
select
    a.name,a.desc,a.reportname,b.manname,b.mandata
from
    product as a inner join
    a.manufacturer as m
where
    m.name like :manufacturer and
    a.description like :description and
    ((a.percentSize <= :sizeMax and
    a.percentSize >= :sizeMin) or
    a.percentSize is null) and
    ((a.wingSpanInches <= :spanMax and
    a.wingSpanInches >= :spanMin) or
    a.wingSpanInches is null) and
    ((a.recommendedAuwMinLbs <= :auwMax and
    a.recommendedAuwMaxLbs >= :auwMin) or
    a.recommendedAuwMaxLbs is null)
]]></query>
```

Not all the search parameters are mandatory (some values I am getting are null). How do I exclude parameters if they are null?

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do. please rephrase

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I think you should take a look at the Criteria API, it makes creating queries of this kind a lot more simple.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`findByExample()`](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects#The_DAO_interfaces).
If the object has a null value field, it is not included in the generated SQL's where clause.

However, this means you cannot use a named query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. You'd have to build the query dynamically (using a `StringBuilder`).

```
if (firName != null) {
    sb.append(" WHERE ....");
}

session.createQuery(sb.toString());
```

Comment: @Bozho:But in named query ,it is manadatory to set all the params right?

Comment: @Bozho:I dont understnad what your saying,I think you got my issue.

Comment: @raj what do you want your code that will handle the result of the query look like?

Comment: @Bozho:  Suppose if i have parameters first name and last name.from my jsp if first name coming as null,i want to remove this parameter from query before it hits the db.

Comment: @ Bozho:Thanks,After preparing clauses ,how can i set The values dynamically to the parameters.

Comment: @raj again, using `if` clasues. `if (firstName != null) query.setParameter("firName", firstName)`

Comment: @ Bozho:Then there is no use here to use Named query right,it is simply like running prepared statement.

Comment: @raj - yes. that's not a named query anymore.

Comment: @ Bozho:Thanks,Is it possible to define the Criteria.Why i choosen named query is becuase we dont have any relationship between tables.Is it possible.

Comment: @raj - perhaps; I've never used the criteria API.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be doing queries straight from a JSP page. Ouch.

You do have to set every parameter (at least, you do with PostgreSQL), but it's okay to set them to null. If they are null, the query you already have will do the right thing, and not apply the corresponding test.

So, you just need to make sure that all the parameters are passed, with any optional ones set to null if they aren't specified.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you add an extra variable eg. :active
then your query shoul look something like this.

```
...
where
(m.name like :manufacturer and 1 = :active) or
(m.name like :manufacturer and a.description like :description  and 2 = :active) or
(m.name like :manufacturer and a.description like :description and a.percentSize <= :sizeMax and 3 = :active) or ...
```

And so on...
With the :active you can then later decide which of the arguments should "count".
Or do nothing by setting :active to e.g null.

Do you get the idea?